# What is this coin and how do I find its value in INR?

Tags: coins

I have a coin like currency with me. We have all gone mad thinking what it is. Help me find what this is.

Front:

[image: Coin (front)]

Back:

[image: Coin (back)]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more related to Numismatic than personal finance.

Comment: @Dheer In my opinion, questions about currency and legal tender are intrinsically linked to personal finance, and should be on-topic.

Comment: @BenMiller coin identification is a vast topic. I am into numismatics and it is a very broad topic on its own. The format is more of discussion board and not Q&A. While you have given the exchange value, it's numismatics value can be way different. Price of stock is off topic as it changes fast, hence exchange rate is also off topic. May be a meta discussion.

Comment: The reverse *says* "Kingdom of Bahrain".  How can you *not* know what it is?

Comment: I don't know that anything has changed about whether or not this should be on-topic, but the answer is that that is a 50 fils [Bahraini coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahraini_dinar#Coins).  As I type this, it's worth about 9 INR or 13 cents USD according to Google.

Comment: There is a [meta question](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2666/10997) discussing whether or not this question is off-topic.

Comment: @Dheer - that is simply not a numismatic coin.  The question has no relation at all to numismatics.  It's just a common Bahraini coin, currency. It's  "Bahrani dime".

Comment: @RonJohn - you know, in fairness I bet 20% of adult Americans literally would never have heard the word "Bahrain" or know that it is "a country".   Not everyone's a Swiss Polyglot Worldtraveller Cosmopolitanite!  :)

Comment: Sigh - everyone should beware that this is an ancient question anyway.  It's so annoying when old questions pop up in the list, so silly and time wasting.

Answer (score 7):

This is a [Bahraini coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahraini_dinar).  It is worth 50 fils, and there are 1000 fils in each Bahraini dinar, so this coin is worth 0.050 BHD.  The current value of this coin is [8.99 INR](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+0.05+bhd+to+inr), or [$0.13 USD](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=convert+0.05+bhd+to+usd).

Comment: Is this information correct? Someone said me that it is a Bahrain Dinar.Can you confirm it is only worth 8 INR?

Comment: @AbhijithAS Take a look at the [Wikipedia article I linked to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahraini_dinar) and read for yourself.  Based on the article, I believe my answer is correct, but I don't have any first hand knowledge about Bahraini currency.

Comment: @AbhijithAS You're welcome.  If you consider your question answered, you can click the checkmark button to the left of this answer.  That will mark your question as "answered."